# Summation Problem involving Reciprocal Binomial coefficients. Find $\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{^nC_r}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17cdM.jpg)

I tried to convert it to a form like $ \displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^n\frac{r(-1^r)}{n^{({}^{n-1}C_{r-1})}}   $

And then write the series backwards and add the two, but this doesn't seem to help.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment that $^nC_r$ is not universal notation, so if you use it in a question be sure to define what you mean. It context I'm guessing you mean n choose r or $\binom{n}{r}$, as I'm used to, but it took me a minute to guess this. It may help to fix your formatting in the later sum as well.

Comment: Nice! The result is $0$ for odd $n$ and  $\frac{2 n+1}{n+1}$ for even $n$.

Comment: @Raffaele I think you mean $2(n+1)/(n+2)$ for even $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael No, no. It's $$\left\{\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{3},\frac{7}{4},\frac{9}{5},\frac{11}{6},\ldots\right\}$$

Comment: @Raffaele For example, if $n=2$, $$\sum_{r=0}^2 (-1)^r/{2 \choose r} = \frac{3}{2} = \frac{2  (n+1)}{n+2}$$ You would have $$\dfrac{2n+1}{n+1}=\frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: It's the same sequence shifted by $1$. I get $3/2$ for $n=1$ and you for $n=2$

Comment: @ggg Thanks for the comment, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.